# Wordpress media file - hover on image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

What i need to do:

I added images to a wordpress post, via the media uploader, from within the visual editor.

On the site when hovering on those images, I want it to do hover-effect for another image with yellow background and opacity and sign of "+".

I tried many things, even old plugin of "[image hover](http://wordpress.org/plugins/hover-image/)", but none worked.

Is there a way to do it only with css? without scripts? if yes - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the css, but it will require some html changes as well.

Here is a [***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GregsFiddle/yNDJq/2/) to verify this is what you want.

```
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');

.size-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.size-thumbnail:hover:before {
    content: "\f067"; 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(255,247,102,0.5);
}
```

Comment: MMMMM thanks... i have a little block in my head... how can i implement it with wordpress , on images that added by visual editor ?

Comment: Which images, thumbnails?

Comment: look on the image of w8 here http://hap.outit.co.il/hap7/   it added via visual editor, media upload.

Comment: Updated the fiddle for your site.  Just copy and paste the css code (top right box) into your css file and include [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) in your header

Comment: also if my code helped you, please select best answer for me!

Comment: But... i need to use also the js no?

Comment: No JS needed.  I updated the code in the example above.  Copy and paste that into your css file.

Comment: Hey thanks, i added to the css your updated code, but hover do nothing... can you check it? new url: http://hap.exactive.co.il/?page_id=22

Comment: i used it now with "nextgen-gallery" plugin and it works for chrome. in Firefox - not. why? i added -moz- to transations